# Basic Auth in Android apps over HTTPS and SSL Connection Automatically

Tags: android, https, sslhandshakeexception

I have done **Basic Auth in Android App over HTTPS connection Dynamically** + Solution of **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

MainActivity.java

you can change your URL and change username and password.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public SSLContext context = null;
    public SSLContext context1 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void doBasicAuth(View view) {
        new check().execute();
    }

    private class Connection extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            int output = connect();
            return output;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            if(result.equals(200)) {
                Intent intent_name = new Intent();
                intent_name.setClass(getApplicationContext(), successful.class);
                startActivity(intent_name);
            }
        }
    }
    private int check() throws IOException {
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                null;
        try {
            Certificate ca = null;
            URL url = new URL("https://xyz.abc.cc/api/scm.config/1.0/orgs");
            SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslCtx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{ new X509TrustManager() {

                private X509Certificate[] accepted;

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                    accepted = xcs;
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return accepted;
                }
            }}, null);

            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslCtx.getSocketFactory());

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                Certificate[] certificates = connection.getServerCertificates();
                System.out.println("cert added");
                ca = certificates[0];

            }
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);

            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
            context1 = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context1.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            url = new URL("https://xyz.abc.cc/api/scm.config/1.0/orgs");

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() { @Override public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; } });
            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("user:pass".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context1.getSocketFactory());
            try {
                System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    System.out.println(in.read());
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.append(line);
                    }
                    System.out.println(out.toString());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/httpButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Https Connection"
    android:onClick="doBasicAuth"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="31dp" />
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=-wyWxLAtPpc

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I just Provide solution of javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.